# Python code error - NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

I am relatively new to writing Python code so this is probably obvious to most of you but I am receiving the following error: NameError: name 'latest_edition' is not defined

```
> # Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

from arcpy.sa import *


#Set input and output locations
in_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/software_versions"
print in_loc
out_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/current/Platform_indices_test.gdb"
print out_loc

#Set workspace location
arcpy.env.workspace = in_loc

index_list =['aqi', 'css']


for ind in index_list:
  search_string = ind + "*_i.tif"
  print search_string
  raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters(search_string,"ALL")

  for i, obj in enumerate(raster_list):
    edition = int(obj[4:6] + obj[8:9])
    if edition > latest_edition:
      latest_edition = edition
      print latest_edition
      latest_raster = obj
  arcpy.CopyRaster_management(latest_raster,out_loc + "/" + latest_raster,"DEFAULTS","","","","","")
```

Comment: Although you are using ArcPy in your script, your problem here is a pure Python one that would be better researched at [so].

Comment: Thank you PolyGeo for the advice.  I will make sure that I post in the correct forum from now on :)

Comment: I would research at that site rather than post because I think similar questions will have already been asked and answered 100s of times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnameerror%5d%20%5bpython%5d%20is%3aquestion&mixed=0

Answer (score 1):

you compare the variable 'latest_edition' before declaration.
Change like this:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

from arcpy.sa import *


#Set input and output locations
in_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/software_versions"
print in_loc
out_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/current/Platform_indices_test.gdb"
print out_loc

#Set workspace location
arcpy.env.workspace = in_loc

index_list =['aqi', 'css']
# ---------- insert this line ------------------
latest_edition = 0

for ind in index_list:
  search_string = ind + "*_i.tif"
  print search_string
  raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters(search_string,"ALL")

  for i, obj in enumerate(raster_list):
    edition = int(obj[4:6] + obj[8:9])
    if edition > latest_edition:
      latest_edition = edition
      print latest_edition
      latest_raster = obj
  arcpy.CopyRaster_management(latest_raster,out_loc + "/" + latest_raster,"DEFAULTS","","","","","")
```

Comment: Thank you Marco.  I have added that line of code, but am now getting the following runtime error:  Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 41, in <module>   File "f:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 12737, in CopyRaster     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. The table name is invalid. No spatial reference exists. The table was not found. [aqi_19_q4_i.tif] Failed to execute (CopyRaster).      Any suggestions?  Much appreciated!

Comment: ChristineF, both variables passed (latest_raster and out_loc+"/"+latest_raster) must have the ".tif" extension. Could you try make the join of exit variable like this: os.path.join(out_loc, latest_raster). Remember the "import os" library